# Can't add Preferences in the PreferenceScreen xml file

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I am new in the Android world. In the structural view of the PreferenceScreen xml file, as I select "PreferenceScreen" and click "Add..." button to add some preferences, an almost blank box pops up with nothing to add or select. I want to add a couple of EditTextPreferences. What might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can select to view the XML source at the bottom left corner of the window. I would recommend doing it this way since you can add some more customization/functionality.

Take a look at this tutorial:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to android,

It is always recommended to add the preferences by writing in  "  ".xml ,instead of using structure

.You can type and press ctrl + shift ,eclipse will show all options available.

For more information Go here - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html